# How to set target URL for googleplus +1 button?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to set googleplus +1 button to address different URL than code locates on.

It is not clear [from documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/), whether to write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone href="myurl"></g:plusone>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone data-href="myurl"></g:plusone>
```

i.e. is tag name is `href` or `data-href`.

I have old code with `href`, `size` and `count` which is apparently not working. Are these tags obsolete?

**UPDATE**

Tag changing didn't help.

**UPDATE 2**

No, documentation is not clear. In the point #1 in section "Setting the +1 target URL" it is written that

[image]

I.e. `href` attribute is referred. Unfortunately, there is no `href` attribute described in the table below.

Comment: In the documentation it is written pretty clear, how to use it. See the first item in [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#tag_parameters) table.

Comment: No, documentation is not clear. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

As a custom tag:

```
<g:plusone data-href='your-url-here...'></g:plusone>
```

As an HTML5 tag:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-href="your-url-here..."></div>
```

If you only have one +1 button on your page, you can also set the canonical url for it, and it will get used for your +1 button. It goes in the `<head>` of you document:

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="page-url-here" />
```

Comment: Dims, if this answer worked for you, will you accept it please?